# SQL Databases in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

If you are using an sql database with a vb.net application, does the user need to have anything extra other than the .net framework installed for the program to run? Meaning, if I simply compile the application, are there any extra steps I need to take to make this work?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well duh, my question was referring to drivers. Do they need any extra .dlls?

Comment: Are you copying the executable to a client machine? Are you getting any error messages?  Does the application rely on any third party code, such as DevExpress controls?  How are you setting the connection string to the SQL Server?

Comment: I am only testing on my dev machine, I have nothing else to test on. The app uses only the standard controls, as it is a rather simple one, so no need for a Ribbon UI or anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment response on the question of having a SQL DB server somewhere:

> Well duh, my question was referring to
>   drivers. Do they need any extra .dlls?

Nope, you should be good to go. :)

The only time you have to worry about this is if you use a 3rd party control or tool that isn't installed with the framework.

Comment: Awesome! That just made my life a lot easier!

Comment: Yup, the basic "database connectivity infrastructure" comes as ADO.NET packaged up in the .NET framework installation. You should be fine